# How to model this multi-tenancy usecase?

Tags: elasticsearch, database-design, architecture, multi-tenant

We are a **multi-tenant** platform.

- The platform has a construct called `Entity`.
- Users can create entities to model any real-life object eg: `Customers, Orders, Payment, Inventory, Cart`, pretty much anything.
- Each entity will have its set of attributes, for example, a customer entity can have: `name, email, phone, address (can be another nested entity)`, etc.
- The requirement is to provide query/OLAP capabilities on these entities. For example, `find all customers where name = 'john'`.
- The requirement includes all types of queries such as `DATE RANGE, CONTAINS, LIKE, NUMERIC RANGE, FULL-TEXT Queries`, etc. We also need `Sorting, Aggregation, Pagination` features.

**Current design**

- We use elasticsearch to store entity data.
- Each tenant is assigned a separate index.
- When an entity is created in a tenant, the corresponding mappings are created inside the associated index. The mappings have roughly the following form:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "Customer": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "values": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        },
        "age": {
          "values": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Order": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "values": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        },
        "eta": {
          "values": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    //... other entities of this tenant
  }
}
```

**Major Problems with this design**

- Ever-growing mappings.
- Frequent updates to mappings and hence the nodes are busy circulating cluster update information, leading to search/indexing latencies and occasional timeouts.
- Existing mappings can't be altered if required. We have to go for the entire re-index procedure.

The current design was able to serve us for a few years until recently when the issues started popping up.

What would be a good design to model the above multi-tenancy requirement? Which database solution and schema modeling will be appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to stick with ES, you'll need to give your tenants more than one index, i.e. one index per tenant/entity instead of one index per tenant. The reasons for this are exactly the ones you mentioned, i.e. ever-growing mapping and the difficulty to update existing mappings.

You'll end up with more indexes for sure (N tenants x M entities) and the challenge will be to properly size those indexes in terms of how many primary shards you need for each of their entities. But I think it's even more difficult now that all entities are stored in a single index per tenant, so it'll turn out to be easier to fan out your tenant index into several.

Another option is to come up with a very generic mapping, which only contains typed fields like `int_field_1`, `int_field_2`, `text_field_1`, `text_field_2`, etc, and you keep a per-tenant mapping between the generic field names and the tenant specific field names:

```
name -> text_field_1
age -> int_field_1
...
```

That way you've less mappings to manage, it's more flexible in terms of what kind of data you can accommodate, but it comes at the price of keeping the above field mapping up-to-date.

In any case, you need to end up having more indexes for your tenants in order to make it easier to manage their mappings and keep their size at bay. it will also allow you to scale better, because it's easier to spread several smaller indices over your data nodes, than very big indexes, especially given [the new sizing recommendation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/size-your-shards.html#field-count-recommendation) made by Elastic.

Comment: how will you provision the resources for 1 index per entity approach?

Comment: There's no magic formula here. If you have the possibility of knowing in advance from the customer approximately the amount of data per entity they have, you have an idea how to size. If not, then you need to start with small indexes (1 primary shard) and then split it out as it approaches the [10-50GB per shard limit](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/size-your-shards.html#shard-size-recommendation)

Comment: suggestions taken. I am open to any DB which can provide most effective solution and not just Elastic.